# Add a dropdown menu to a clickable table row in Angular 6 with Bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm working on an account book with a table, which shows all available accounts.
Each row shows basic information about a specific account and by clicking on a row Angular routes to a detail view for that account.

Now I want to include a dropdown menu in the last or very right cell of each row, where users can select a specific action related to accounts, i. e. "Enter revenue", "Enter expense", ...

With the provided code below, I'm not able to select an option of the dropdown, because Angular immediately routes to the detail view, because of course I'm clicking the row as well, when clicking the dropdown.

```
<table class="table accounts-body">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Accounttype</th>
              <th>Accountnumber</th>
              <th>Balance</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="account" *ngFor="let account of 
                depositor.bankAccounts" (click)="onAccountClicked(account)">
              <td class="table-entry">{{account.accountType}}</td>
              <td class="table-entry">{{account.accountNumber}}</td>
              <td class="table-entry">{{account.balance | number: '1.2-2'}} EUR</td>
              <td class="table-entry">
                <select (change)="onActionSelected($event)>
                  <option>enter revenue</option>
                  <option>enter expense</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="total">
              <td colspan="2">Sum:</td>
              <td colspan="2">
                {{getTotal(depositor) | number: '1.2-2'}} EUR
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

How can I prevent Angular to route to the details view when clicking the dropdown menu to select an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent the bubbling of the click event when you click on the select.

Something along the lines of

```
<select (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" ...
```

Comment: Thank you :) That did the job. Didn't think about bubbling events.